# Livedata inside fragment with view Model issue using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey guys i am facing a problem that in fragment I am observing some live data but when i go to next fragment and come back to previous fragment I am still getting the last data in my live data because i observed the live data again and view model was in memory so like how to solve this problem i just want to observe live data for the first time.

Comment: I don't get your question, butmaybe the `livedata.removeObservers(lifecycle)` or `livedata.hasActiveObservers()` methods may help you.

Comment: I think the thing you're looking for is something called `SingleLiveEvent` which is a special type of live data that emits value only once to all unique observers.

Comment: You can go through this one: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Comment: Emitting data again is the property of LiveData. If you want  to receive event only once use MutableSharedFlow

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel must be destroyed when the view gets destroyed. For that, the lifecycle of the ViewModel must be defined by `viewLifeCycleOwner`. If you have used something else in that place then change it to the above-mentioned variable.

Also, could you share a bit of code so that, we can look at the problem deeply.

Comment: //View Model Initialization Code
private val viewModel by lazy {
        val factory = ChatViewModel.ChatViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application)
        ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[ChatViewModel::class.java]
    }


ViewModel Class

class ChatViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
}

//Live Data Observer Code
viewModel.vehicleDetails.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                setVehicleDetails(it)
        }